# Addition md5 hash to password (Ruby on Rails)

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, activerecord, hash, md5

```
def formsubmit
    @user = MyModel.new(:username => params[:username], :password => params[:password])
    if @user.valid?
        #@user.password = Digest::MD5.hexdigest(params[:password]) ???
        @user.save
    end
end
```

How to add md5 hash to password?

Comment: Use bcrypt, don't use MD5! MD5 is nowadays not much better than storing plain text for passwords. Even if you salted it (which you are not here). Bcrypt is the same technology (secure hashing), but hardened against typical attacks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is usually recommended not to design your own authentication logic as it is a common task and it is somewhat easy to make mistakes in it (such as using unsalted MD5).

You should either use a tutorial, such as

http://railscasts.com/episodes/250-authentication-from-scratch

or an out-of-the-box solution, such as

https://github.com/plataformatec/devise